# After Insert trigger on table1 with Update IF condition on table2

Tags: mysql

I want to create trigger 'after insert' on table1

If i insert record in Table1 
it will check corresponding ID in table2 and update the status of 
corresponding ID in table2.
there is additional condition on table2.
status of that ID should be Null.

my attempt so far.
but its not working

```
CREATE  TRIGGER 'table1_AFTER_INSERT` AFTER INSERT ON `table1` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  update table2 a 
  set a.status= 'coordination pass',
  where a.ID = new.ID and a.status is Null;
END
```

Comment: No error,
it doesnot update corresponding ID in another table.although its status is Null

Comment: can you edit your question as a readable form. i am not able to edit it some body hold as a edit

Comment: as i seen your trigger there is two error first is  with table name  you use `'` single quote and second is  `set a.status= 'coordination pass',` comma at last

Comment: even after rectifying syntax error , it doesn't update status of target table

Answer (score 0):

You have many sintax errors like comma after `set a.status= 'coordination pass',` or in trigger name definition etc. Here is the correct triger sintax

```
CREATE TRIGGER `table1_AFTER_INSERT` AFTER INSERT ON `table1`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

    UPDATE `table2` a 
    SET a.status= 'coordination pass'
    WHERE a.ID = NEW.ID AND a.status is NULL;

END
```

Comment: even after rectifying syntax error , it doesn't update status of target table

Comment: 1) trigger creation is worked for you yes ? without any error ?  2) now when you mane insert to table1 the current row index was lets say 12 you have in table2 row which id was 12 and its status not updated ?

Answer (score 0):

As i seen your trigger there is two error first is with table name you use ' single quote and second is set a.status= 'coordination pass', comma at last

```
CREATE TRIGGER table1_AFTER_INSERT
AFTER INSERT ON table1` 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
   UPDATE table2 a 
   SET a.status= 'coordination pass'
   WHERE a.ID = new.ID AND a.status is Null;
END;
```

Comment: even after rectifying syntax error , it doesn't update status of target table

Comment: SHOW TRIGGERS LIKE 'table1_AFTER_INSERT%'\G  can you provide the output of this query